# split file into multiple pieces

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, split, gawk

Problem: 
given a file `samplein`, it can be split up into multiple pieces as follows:

```
$ cat samplein
START
Unix
Linux
START
Solaris
Aix
SCO

$ awk '/START/{x="F"++i;}{print > x}' samplein
$ ls F*
F1  F2

$ cat F1
START
Unix
Linux

$ cat F2
START
Solaris
Aix
SCO
```

The above was recipe 5 from [this page](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/awk-10-examples-to-split-file-into.html).
However, I had the case where the pattern (`START` in this case) didn't occur at the first line.

But if we append a newline to `samplein` the same code/recipe doesn't work any more!

```
$ echo -e "firstline\n$(cat samplein)" > samplein
$ cat samplein
$ awk '/START/{x="F"++i;}{print > x}' samplein
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=samplein FNR=1) fatal: expression for `>' redirection has null string value
```

Please also explain in the answer how this awk command works in the first place. The only context I had used awk previously was `{BEGIN}{loop over all lines}{END}`. This recipe looks slightly different from that!

Comment: You might want to read some of the information linked at http://awk.info/?Learn

Comment: Unless you are using this problem as a learning exercise for awk, you might want to look at `csplit` if your system provides it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `x="F0"` to the beginning so the target file is always defined, even if the first line doesn't contain the pattern:

```
awk 'BEGIN { x="F0" ; } /START/{x="F"++i;}{print > x}'
```

The above breaks down to this pseudo code:

```
### -> BEGIN { x="F0" ; }
i=0 # implicit
x="F0" # explicit
loop through file

### -> /START/{x="F"++i;}
if ( line contains "START" ) output file is F(next i value) ;

### -> {print > x}
print line to output file

endloop
```

Keep in mind that all clauses like `BEGIN`, `END` ,  `{ ...}` are optional.